# Wordpress custom JS Modal code not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, modal-dialog

I know I am going to facepalm after this one but I am missing something so simple and cannot figure it out.

I have a php file in my custom plugin where I want to add a button to open a modal popup.

I followed this guide: https://sabe.io/tutorials/how-to-create-modal-popup-box

- HTML - added to php file in question - button shows
- CSS - added to theme's advanced additional css section
- JS - added to theme's advanced additional JS section

Clicking the button just does nothing.

I spoke to the theme editor but after waiting 48 hours the response I got was:

> You can add js code to the Appearance / Theme Options / Advanced
>   Setting / Custom JS
>
> and css code to Appearance / Theme Options / Advanced Setting / Custom
>   CSS
>
> add_action('wp_footer', function() {
>
> // put your modal code here
>
> });

What modal code would he be talking about baring in mind we have already covered the JS and CSS elements.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: No, clicking the button is not triggering anything at all.

Comment: We can not possibly tell you what you might have done wrong, if you don’t show us what you actually did first of all. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Add your css and js on the page for testing, and check popup once and console error.

Comment: I get no console error - so confusing